# Python dictionary only scrollling through the last entry

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the follwoing script

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

d = {edit_database: utm_database, 'GTI_EDITING.DBO.': 'GTI_PUB_UTM.DBO.'}
e = {edit_database: wm_database, 'GTI_EDITING.DBO.': 'GTI_PUB_WM.DBO.'}

arcpy.env.workspace = edit_database
listBoundaries= arcpy.ListDatasets("*Boundaries")
for bounds in listBoundaries:
    inBound =os.path.join(edit_database, bounds)
    arcpy.env.workspace= inBound
    listBoundFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    inpBound1 = []   
    for BoundC in listBoundFC:
        inputBoundFC = os.path.join(inBound, BoundC)
        outputBoundUTM = multiple_replace(inputBoundFC, d)
        outputBoundWM = multiple_replace(inputBoundFC, e)
        inpBound2 = (BoundC.replace('GTI_EDITING.DBO.', ''))
        inpBound1.append(inpBound2)
    print inpBound1

arcpy.env.workspace = utm_database
listBound1 = arcpy.ListDatasets("*Boundaries")
for Boundout in listBound1:
    OuBound = os.path.join( utm_database, Boundout)
    arcpy.env.workspace = OuBound
    listBoundFCoutput = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    outBound1 = []
    for fcoutBound in listBoundFCoutput:
        outBound2 = (fcoutBound.replace('GTI_PUB_UTM.DBO.',''))
        outBound1.append(outBound2)

f = 0
g = 0
if inpBound1[f] <> outBound1[g]:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inputBoundFC, outputBoundUTM)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inputBoundFC, outputBoundWM)
    print (outputBoundUTM + " and " + outputBoundWM + " have been updated .")
f+=1
g+=1
```

I have set it up so that it for the features to scroll through, however it is only going to the last feature I have in the dictionary.  I have tried everything and either it goes just to the first one or last dictionary entry.   Does anyone have a clue what is going on or do dictionaries just don't work and I should do a series of for and if loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arcpy.env.workspace = edit_database
listBoundaries= arcpy.ListDatasets("*Boundaries")
for bounds in listBoundaries:
    inBound =os.path.join(edit_database, bounds)
    arcpy.env.workspace= inBound
    listBoundFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    inpBound1 = []
    for BoundC in listBoundFC:
        inputBoundFC = os.path.join(inBound, BoundC)
        outputBoundUTM = multiple_replace(inputBoundFC, d)
        outputBoundWM = multiple_replace(inputBoundFC, e)
        inpBound2 = BoundC.replace('GTI_EDITING.DBO.', '')
        inpBound1.append(inpBound2)
        print inpBound1
        if inpBound1[f] not in outBound1:
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inputBoundFC, outputBoundUTM)
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inputBoundFC, outputBoundWM)
            print (outputBoundUTM + " and " + outputBoundWM + " have been updated
```

I found that the easiest way is to first get the list you are checking against,  and then build the query to check it against it